# Negative and complex number eigenvalues for PCA

Tags: python, scipy, pca, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have produced a correlation matrix `my_corr = rtn.corr(method = 'pearson')` and I did the PCA composition on that matrix from scipy : `eig_vals, eig_vecs = linalg.eig(my_corr)`. However I get negative and complex number for eigen values like
-4.33309269e-16+2.336829340-16j. If I `use  linalg.eigh` instead of `linalg.eig`, I got real values but a lot of negative values too. Why that happen? Thanks for your help

Comment: The value `-4.33309269e-16+2.336829340-16j` is likely a numerical approximation of a zero eigenvalue.  When you use `eigh`, are the negative eigenvalues as small as this (i.e. all on the order of 1e-16)?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information like snippet output of `linalg.eig` and `linalg.eigh` or the `rtn` dataframe to begin with, there can be multiple causes. For one, `eigh` automatically sorts your eignvalues as opposed to `eig`. `Eigh` also assumes you have a symmetric `my_corr`. More information about this: [Difference between linalg.eigh and linalg.eig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45434989/numpy-difference-between-linalg-eig-and-linalg-eigh)